# Validate if data already exist in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to find if the data already exist in the database. However it doesn't enter the loop. It always go to the else

This is my validation part, it always goes to the else part
full code is in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/k2wZ1N5s)

```
private void validate(final String Song) {
    final DatabaseReference RootRef;
    RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (!(dataSnapshot.child("Participants").child(Song).exists()))
            {
                HashMap<String, Object> userdataMap = new HashMap<>();
                userdataMap.put("song", Song);
                RootRef.child("Participants").child(Song).updateChildren(userdataMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "This song already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            else    {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Your have choosed your song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               // Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }}
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Participants").child(Song);
RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
{
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
           Toast.makeText(Register.this, "This song already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
        }
        else    {
            HashMap<String, Object> userdataMap = new HashMap<>();
            userdataMap.put("song", Song);
            RootRef.setValue(userdataMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "This song successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });

        }}
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

If you want to check exist a song, you can give it as a reference. If datasnapshot is exists then your database has the song. If not, you can add the song to the database.